# $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n^2} e^{-\frac{x}{n}}$ converges uniformly to zero

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n^2} e^{-\frac{x}{n}}$, I want to show $f_n(x) \rightrightarrows 0$, i.e., $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $0$.

---

Here is my trial:

Apparently, from l'Hôpital's theorem, I know $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$.

So from the definition of uniformly convergent, I need to find $N$ such that $\forall x$, $|f_n(x)| <\epsilon$, $\forall n \geq N$. i.e., $|\frac{x}{n^2}e^{-\frac{x}{n}}| < \epsilon$ and I stuck with this issue.

---

The answer in textbook says : Use $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\infty} f_n(x) dx=1$

I Know $f_n(x)$ is continuous(Since it is a product of two continuous function), so $f_n(x)$ over a closed interval is integrable. Note that $\int f_n(x)= - \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{n}}(n+x)}{n}$, so I have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\infty}f_n(x)dx=1$.

But this does not tells $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$, furthermore if $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly, then limit and integral can exchange and that means $1=\int_0^{\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty} 0 dx$ but integral over $0$ is $0$ so I got confused.

Comment: I assume $x\geq 0$. Then we just observe that $te^{-t}\leq e^{-1}$ for $t\geq 0$. Thus, $$
f_n (x) = \frac{1}{n}\frac{x}{n}e^{ - \frac{x}{n}}  \le \frac{1}{n}e^{ - 1}
$$ for $x\geq 0$. Perhaps others will comment on how to use the textbook hint. I belive what I said is the simplest way to prove uniform convergence. Uniform convergence is not enough for changing the order of the limit and integration. For that, you need an integrable majorant which does not depend on $n$.

Comment: The domain is unbounded, so uniform convergence does not imply that you can switch limit and integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are talking about uniform convergence on $[0,\infty)$.

The function $ye^{-y}$ is  a bounded continuous function on this interval. (It is continuous and tends to $0$ as $ y \to \infty$).

Let $ye^{-y} \leq C$ for all $y \geq 0$. Put $f=\frac  x  n$ and conclude that $0 \leq f_n(x) \leq \frac   C n $. This proves uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $0$ on $[0, \infty)$.